# Generate an image from div adjusting canvas size

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I have a code which transform a DIV HTML in a PNG image, it work succesfully.
But when i export to PDF in big size, it loose quality, probably because it's was created minor in canvas than the original size.

So, i resized the canvas for width 2482px and height 3508px, this is the size which i want generate the PDF. But the image stay small, dont getting the total area of box, filling about 1/16 their. See:

```
html2canvas($('#quadro'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
        img = new Image();
        img.src = imgData;
        img.onload = function() {
            localStorage.setItem('imagem', imgData);
            window.location.href = 'escolherMoldura.html';
        }
        img.onerror = function() { alert('there was an image load error :('); };
    },
    scale: 2,
    dpi: 300,
    width: 2482,
    height: 3508,
    letterRendering: true,
});
```

See, it should be filled all the box.

[image: foto]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

With the use of this Code you can high resolution images

```
saveSvgAsPng($('#quadro'), "quadro.png", {scale: 2});
```

for more details use this [link](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng).

Comment: @michelmfreitas try above solution I think this will help you.